# Maximum distance from the origin to the surface

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I am having trouble getting the maximum distance from the origin to the surface

$$
    \frac{x^4}{16} +\frac{y^4}{81} + z^4 = 1
$$

Knowing I have to maximize $x^2 +y^2+ z^2$ and that the constrain is the above surface.

My Lagrangian is:

$$
    L(x,y,z,\lambda) = x^2+y^2+z^2 +\lambda(1- \frac{x^4}{16} - \frac{y^4}{81} - z^4).
$$

And doing the partial derivatives i get:

$$
  \frac{\partial L}{\partial x} = 2x-\frac{x^3\lambda}{4}; \\
  \frac{\partial L}{\partial y} = 2y-\frac{4y^3\lambda}{81};\\
   \frac{\partial L}{\partial z} = 2z-4z^3\lambda;
$$

After getting that, I don't know how to proceed in order to get the maximum distance.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Can you identify which function you need to maximize and which restriction you should take?

Comment: When you actually set up your problem, one trick is to maximize the *square* of the distance (which gets rid of a square root that would otherwise make a mess in your calculations).  Note that finding the point on the surface that maximizes the square of the distance from the origin will also maximize the distance from the origin.

Comment: @GitGud I believe i have to maximize x^2 + y^2 + z^2, and the constraint is the above surface.

Comment: You are correct. I suggest you now proceed in the usual manner as far as you can and post your work in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From there you have a system of four equations, so you can use substitution to eliminate variables and solve it.

$2x-\frac{x^3\lambda}{4}=0 \\ 2y-\frac{y^3\lambda}{81}=0 \\ 2z-4z^3\lambda=0 \\ \frac{x^4}{16}+\frac{y^4}{81}+z^4=1$

Using the third one:

$2z-4z^3\lambda = 0 \\ 1-2z^2\lambda=0 \\ \lambda=\frac{1}{2z^2}$

Plugging that into the first equation:

$2x-\frac{x^3}{8z^2}=0 \\ 16z^2=x^2 \\ 4|z|=|x|$

Using the value for $\lambda$ in the second equation:

$2y-\frac{y^3}{162z^2}=0 \\ 324z^2 = y^2 \\ 18|z|=|y| $

Then putting all the values in terms of z in the last equation:

$ \frac{(4z)^4}{16}+\frac{(18z)^4}{81}+z^4=1 \\ 16z^4+1296z^4+z^4=1 $

$ 1313z^4 = 1$

$z=\pm\frac{1}{{}^4\sqrt{1313}}, y = \pm\frac{18}{{}^4\sqrt{1313}}, x=\pm\frac{4}{{}^4\sqrt{1313}} $

Please double check my math, it looks like it's correct, but I'm not positive.